# with django app, how to link to image in .css file

Tags: django

So normally in a website, I make   and in the CSS, I do

```
 #logo {
     background: url(../images/logo.jpg);
}
```

however, no since I am using a django project, my image is in

```
C:\Users\me\Documents\mysite\myapp\static\images
```

and my .css file is in

```
C:\Users\me\Documents\mysite\myapp\static\css
```

in settings.py, my static_root is

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'C:/Users/me/Documents/mysite/myapp/static'
```

I tried doing

```
#logo {
    background: url({{ STATIC_URL }}/images/logo.jpg);
}
```

but that didn't work. Any idea what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have both directories in the same path "static", just do as usual:

```
#logo {
    background: url(../images/logo.jpg);
}
```